# VSCode vs Goland linter

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, goland, linter

I wonder if the VSCode golang linter used in this VSCode extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=golang.go
and the linter being used in Jetbrains Goland are the same or not. If not what are the differences?

I did not find anything talking about it, so external sources to read about it and the linter, in general, will be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- In VSCode, you can specify the lint tool as you like:
  [image]
- Goland implements its own linter, you can browse those rules in [File->Settings->Editor->Inspections->Go], but you can also custom your linters:

https://dev.to/s0xzwasd/configure-revive-go-linter-in-goland-2ggl